# EF Duplicating Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When attempting to update my Entity Framework model from the database using Database First, any Navigation Properties that were already present on the Entity models are added again with a numbered suffix (e.g. Order would have  Order.Items and Order.Items2).

How can I update the model from the database without having to clear the edmx and create a "fresh" model every time?

Comment: When you update a EF model, you have the wizard where you can choose options to add, update, etc... Is the wizard offering you to add the same tables already created?

Comment: @XurxoGarcia If I do nothing but let it Refresh the models that are currently tracked, the duplicates are added. I usually get around this by selecting all on the designer, remove them from the model, and add them again through the wizard.

Comment: @usmanlqbal This is not a code problem, but rather a problem working through the edmx designer.

Comment: I think could be a problem using Database First when you modify something in the tables according this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757860/entity-framework-database-first-multiple-relations-to-same-table-naming-conven) Read the comments to the first answer for details